# Buzz (vibes) at o'clock hours?

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Very basic question that I've been trying to figure out by myself for a couple hours but can't solve it.

So I'm creating my first watchface for Pebble and I want the watch to buzz (vibrate) every hour. You remember some digital watches make a "beep" at o'clock times? Well something like that.

I figure it out the most simple way to do it is:

```
if (tick_time->tm_min == 0) {
    vibes_short_pulse();
}
```

It works great. Now I have a little bug. During that minute, if the window is re-created (for example, if you go to the timeline or open a watchapp and go back quickly to my watchface) the update_time() is called again so it buzzes again. Not a huge bug but kinda annoying.

I tried to workaround with a boolean flag.

```
static bool vibed = false;
```

And then,

```
if (tick_time->tm_min != 0) {
    vibed = false;
}

if (tick_time->tm_min == 0 && vibed == false) {
    vibes_short_pulse();
    vibed = true;
}
```

But apparently, everytime the window is re-created the flag goes back to "false" no matter what.

I don't know how to solve it. If you have a hint for me, would be appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Store the last hour it vibrated, only vibrate and update that stored hour if minites is zero and the hour differs. But the framework might provide a better way (why is that bound to display update?)

Comment: where are you declaring vibed?  it'd help if you posted more code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking minutes for zero, check for hour change event, e.g.:

```
void tick_handler(struct tm *tick_time, TimeUnits units_changed)
{

  // Some other code that display/process time  

  // on hour change do a short buzz
  if (units_changed & HOUR_UNIT) {
      vibes_short_pulse();
  }


}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, what's "HOUR_UNIT"? Thanks.

Comment: @AirieFenix when your timer tick event fires, `unit_changed` argument contains bit-representation of what caused the tick - it could be second change; second change and minute change; second change, minute change and hour change. To distinguish between them you do a binary AND between that parameter and one of the enum values described here: https://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Event_Service/TickTimerService/#TimeUnits. HOUR_UNIT represent hours, and if that operation resulted in non-zero value - you know that hour actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remember the hour of your last buzz. Only buzz if it's different. So:

```
//initialize to impossible hour so it works the first time
static int lastBuzzHour=-1;
if (tick_time->tm_hour !=lastBuzzHour) {
    vibes_short_pulse();
    // now that you've buzzed, remember it so you don't retrigger
    lastBuzzHour=tick_time->tm_hour;
    }
```